# can't solve expected ) before * token error

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, prototype, header-files

I can't find what is wrong with my code in C:

error.h

```
#ifndef ERROR_H_INCLUDED
#define ERROR_H_INCLUDED

void myfunc(bool**,int); //error line 1

#endif
```

Here is the function declaration:

error.c

```
#include "error.h"
    void myfunc(bool **rel,int num){ //error line 2

    //function code here
    }
```

The call of the function is :

main.c

```
#include "error.h"

int main(){
    bool **rel;
    int num;
    myfunc(rel,num);

return 0;
}
```

The above code returns the error

> expected ')' before '*' token

at the error line 1 and error line 2.I put the function code in comments and i still have this error.I know that, that kind of error is a missing ; or ) at the most times but i spend hours and didn't find the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bool` type is not recognized, you need to include `stdbool.h` in your `error.h` header.